# Difference of Selichot timing

Tags: selichot

Common Nusach Ashkenaz is to recite the first Selichot at "midnight" and all the other Selichot prior to Shacharit.

Why is there this timing difference? Why not have all the Selichot at midnight or all before Shacharit?